# Rails form_for checkbox to select all on a collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put in my form_for a checkbox to apply a select all/deselect all that would update the checkboxes for the collection_check_boxes.

At the moment I have the following (Slim style):

```
=tb_form_for [:admin, @logo do |f|  
 = f.tb_select :region_id, options_from_collection_for_select(holder, :id, :name, @logo.region_id), multiple: true, prompt: 'Select One'
 = f.collection_check_boxes :region_id, Region.all, :id, :name, class: 'something'
 = f.tb_save_buttons('Logo', admin_logos_path)
```

For some reason I can't figure out putting in a stupid check_box with 'Select All' as if I put f.tb_check_box I get wrong number of arguments (given 0, expect 1..2). That's problem one. The other issue would be to actually hit all the regions being displayed on the collection_check_boxes.

I actually tried to say screw it and do a by default marked by default with the following:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :region_id, Region.all, :id, :name do |s|
 .collection-check-box
  = s.check_box(checked: true)
  = s.label
```

Which results in: An unexpected error occurred: Bad Request specifically: Rack::QueryParser::ParameterTypeError (expected Array (got String) for param `region_id').

So how can I add in a checkbox that applies a select all on a collection_check_box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check box anywhere on the page

```
= check_box_tag "", nil, nil, class: "selectall-checkbox"
```

and some Javascript

```
$(".selectall-checkbox").change(function(){
  $(".your-checkbox-class").prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"))
})
```